# Would this be considered a lemma? Does it have a name?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

> It is also a consequence of P7 (the existence of multiplicative
>   inverses) that if $a \cdot b = 0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

This is from *Calculus*, M. Spivak, 2008, chapter 1, "Basic Properties of Numbers". A short proof is given.

Would this statement be considered a lemma?  In working thru the chapter 1 exercises, it seems to do an awful lot of work.

In showing when $(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2$, for example, you end up looking at when $-2xy=0$, so when $xy=0$.  By the statement under consideration, your solution is when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

If this statement *would* be considered a lemma, does it have a name?

Since it is essentially stating "the product zero always has zero among its factors", I have taken to calling it "the Zero Factor Lemma" – but I would like to know if it is already known as something else.

Comment: I have previously seen it called the *Zero Product Property*.

Comment: @TheoBendit that is what we called it in my middle school

Comment: I see now that this is what wikipedia calls it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, this statement is known as the *Null Factor Law*. There are many other variations of this, but all the names refer to the same thing. I am aware that those who were educated in America probably called it the *Zero Product* as well.

The Null Factor Law is especially useful when dealing with solving quadratics and other polynomials. e.g.

\begin{align}
-2 &=x^2-6x+3 \\
0& = x^2-6x+5\\
& = (x-5)(x-1) \\
\therefore ~&x=5 ~\text{or} ~ x=1
\end{align}

Comment: I was educated in Australia. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit Aha same, but I was from WA. Anywho, these names all refer to the same thing, and no particular name is more 'right' than the other.